# why is there space on the left?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul style="background: blue; list-style: none; width: 40px; height: 40px; color: white">
  <li style="float: left; width: 20px; background: red">a</li>
  <li style="float: left; width: 20px; background: green; height: 40px">b</li>
</ul>
```

That bit of HTML / CSS seems to producing a ul that's 80px wide - not 40px wide. And I'm not sure why. Any ideas? Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qJvmM/

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is no margin and padding?

Answer (score 3):

Because `ul` has normally a padding by default.

You need to reset it to zero:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the default margin and padding of ul

```
<ul style="background: blue; list-style: none; width: 40px; height: 40px; color: white;margin:0; padding:0">
  <li style="float: left; width: 20px; background: red">a</li>
  <li style="float: left; width: 20px; background: green; height: 40px">b</li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qJvmM/2/)**